# How do you make an account for Pokemon Go

Tags: pokemon-go

How do you make a Pokemon Go account?

Answer (score 1):

Download the app here: **[iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/nz/app/pokemon-go/id1094591345?mt=8)** or **[Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nianticlabs.pokemongo&hl=en)**

Open it and you'll see a screen that says "Sign up with". You can then select either to sign up using your **Google account** or make a **[Pokemon Club account](https://club.pokemon.com/us/pokemon-trainer-club/sign-up/)**.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You do not make a specific Pokemon Go account. You either log in with a Pokemon Club account, or sign in with a Google account.

[You can create a Pokemon Club account here](https://club.pokemon.com/us/pokemon-trainer-club/sign-up/), however, there are a lot of reports that this service is currently down due to server stress. I have personally been unable to create an account. If you are told "Something went wrong, don't worry, we're on it!", either retry later, or opt for the Google account.

If you wish to sign in with your Google account, simple select "sign in with Google". If you are on an android phone, you should automatically sign in with the account currently logged in. If you need to create a new Google account, though, [you can find that here](https://accounts.google.com/signup).

<sup>Please note that you will need the assistance of a parental guardian for either, if you are under the age of 13. That should not be a problem for our signed-up members, as being over the age of 13 is a requirement for creating a SE account.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

When you first open the app you can just sign in using your Google account that you have associated with your phone or you can make your own account through Pokemon Go when the app first launches.

[image]